# Can not use Heroku CLI in a Docker environment

Tags: docker, heroku

While working on a Ruby app that's using Heroku CLI for deployment, I stumbled upon an issue trying to integrate the whole thing into a Docker Compose workflow and microservices architecture.

Long story short, I am running a container that runs the command: `heroku local:start -p 5000` (start a local Heroku server and expose port 5000, so the Heroku app is accessible at http://localhost:5000).

I bind to port 5000 of the container to port 5000 on the host machine. When I visit http://localhost:5000 on the host machine, I can not access the Heroku app. The same thing works perfectly if I run the command in a non-Docker environment.

I am pretty experienced with Docker and port forwarding so I am almost certain the issue is not with the compose file or how ports are forwarded. The issue appears to be with the Heroku CLI and how it exposes the port to the environment it's running in.

To reproduce the issue, just checkout this commit and run `docker-compose up`: https://github.com/Dzhuneyt/12factor/commit/5bdfc417ce57eb916c42fdc76bae51e4df30549c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this will work if you bind to `0.0.0.0`

```
# Procfile
web: bundle exec ruby web.rb -p $PORT -o 0.0.0.0
```

Also, for convenience, to avoid rebuilding on each debug cycle, I would add a volume mount:

```
# docker-compose.yml
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build: ./
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to check the basics; once you start the service and wait some seconds does 'docker ps' show the service running? If not does 'docker logs {service_name}' provide any output? IT sounds like you have the networking / port configuration correct; this is why I am focusing on the service output. However, if the service IS running, can you 'telnet localhost 5000' and receive a successful connection?